# PyTorch: Batch Outer-Addition

Tags: python, pytorch

I have two PyTorch tensors: `A` and `B`, both of shape `(b, c, 3)`. I want to make outer product `C` of `A` and `B` so that the resulting shape is `(b, c, 3, 3)`, and replace the multiplication operation with addition. How should I do it?

Answer (score 6):

You can add a corresponding singleton dimension:

```
C = A[..., None] + B[..., None, :]
```

For example, with batch and channel dimensions equal to 1 (`b=1, c=1`):

```
import torch
A = torch.tensor([[[1, 2, 3.]]]) 
B = torch.tensor([[[4., 5., 6.]]])
A[..., None] + B[..., None, :]
Out[ ]:
tensor([[[[5., 6., 7.],
          [6., 7., 8.],
          [7., 8., 9.]]]])
```